# How to select odd numbers from a matrix?

Tags: julia

How do you select odd numbers from a matrix larger than 29?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/collections/#Base.filter):

`filter(x->isodd(x)&&x>29, M)`

Here, `x->isodd(x)&&x>29` is an [anonymous function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1), specifying your filter criterium, and `M` is your matrix.

*Example:*

```
julia> M = rand(1:50, 3,3)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 20  42  35
 23   6  31
 28   4   4

julia> filter(x->isodd(x)&&x>29, M)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 35
 31
```

Alternatively, you can use [array comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions-1):

```
julia> [x for x in M if isodd(x) && x>29]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:                
 35                                      
 31
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but you probably shouldn't use `&&` in the anonymous function. `&&` short-circuits, which means it introduces a branch, and branches are slow compared to `isodd` and a `>` operation. Replace `&&` with `&` in your example, and I get an almost 3x speed increase on a 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: They don't compute the same thing though? Compare `isodd(31)&&31>29` to `isodd(31)&31>29`.

Comment: You just need to parenthesize correctly due to operator precedence: `isodd(31) & (31>29)`. Cf. `Base.operator_precedence(:&)` and `Base.operator_precedence(:>)`.

Comment: @crstnbr They compute the same thing, but compare the assembly instructions that is generated by `&&` vs `&`. There's a jump instruction in the former, not the latter. But again, it depends on how precious your microseconds are :)

Comment: There's also the possibility of using logical indexing: `M[isodd.(M) .& (M .>29)]`. Which way is more efficient may vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
using Statistics; 
A = round.(rand(5,5)*10) 
odd = A[(rem.(A,2).>0) .& (A.>29)]
```